# How to decode raw data (non-ascii char) from a barcode scanner

Tags: java, vb.net, decode, barcode

Me and my dev team have a project that .... us from using a handheld barcode scanner. In order to do the job we have to convert the barcode scanner signal into a raw data and send that data trough RS232 to our PC and then process it with VB.net app. I already got the raw data that i want to process, the problem is the raw data only contain non-printable ascii char that starting from 220 up to 255. my question is there any method to decode the raw data into a meaningful printable-ascii (in any language like java,ruby, etc)?

Scanner used is [Solutions BS100](http://solution.co.id/bs100.php). 
The default setting for the scanner is outputting it's data trough USB and it's autodetected as HID keyboard, this isn't a common approach but sometimes as an egineer on my team I have try another one. so I think I captured it properly tough a custom hardware for serial connection needed. I removed the default USB port and change it to rj45 signal with MAX487 IC and then convert it back to rs232 level so I can feed the signal directly to COM1 of my PC

Data returned:

```
250 224 250 221 255 224 221 255 248 224 248 221 255 224 253 255 221 255 224 221 255 221 255 224 221 255 253 255 224 221 255 221 255 224 253 255 253 255 224 221 255 221 255 224 253 255 246 224 246 233 224 233
```

From image:
[image: Image scanned]

Comment: What's the model of the handheld barcode reader?

Comment: here is the specs http://solution.co.id/bs100.php

Comment: Just to confirm: Are you sure that you're capturing the data properly? Every scanner of that type I've ever encountered acts as a sort of "keyboard wedge," outputting characters commonly found on a standard keyboard.

Comment: It has an USB port: is the "raw data" obtained from reading that? You'll need some sort of programmer's manual telling you what the data means.

Comment: Justin Ryan . The default setting for the scanner is outputting it's data trough USB and it's autodetected as HID keyboard, this isn't a common approach but sometimes as an egineer on my team i have try another one.  so i think i captured it properly tough a custom hardware for  serial connection needed

Comment: laune, no i removed the default USB port and change it to rj45 signal with MAX487 IC and then convert it back to rs232 level so i can feed the signal directly to COM1 of my PC,

Comment: Can you add an example barcode with the result output after scanning it to your post?

Comment: +1 to Justin. What if apply black-box abstraction to your barcode scanner and decode output with known barcode?

Comment: 250
224
250
221
255
224
221
255
248
224
248
221
255
224
253
255
221
255
224
221
255
221
255
224
221
255
253
255
224
221
255
221
255
224
253
255
253
255
224
221
255
221
255
224
253
255
246
224
246
233
224
233

Comment: and related raw barcode image?

Comment: How did you remove the USB port and replace it with MAX487 IC? Does the scanner need to be configured for serial COM port?

Comment: Swinders it's USB port is detacheable , look at this https://learn.adafruit.com/barcode-scanner/cable-connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have changed the scanner cable from a USB to serial configuration you would usually need to configure the scanner interface to use the serial connection (see this [example](https://learn.adafruit.com/barcode-scanner/configure)). Once the serial interface has been configured you should get the ASCII characters returned (49 48 49 48 48 48 48 48 48 55 51).

Comment: duh i must admit i was so naive

Comment: Some of these devices can also be set to appear as a virtual COM port when using the USB connection.

Comment: @Muhammad_Sigit_Dude If this answer was useful don't forget you can vote it up as well as accept it